# How to Sort data of collection types on STRAPI Admin?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, content-management-system, strapi

I want to sort table data coming with created_at DESC in STRAPI Admin panel.
I want to load data in created_at DESC order default.

How to achieve this?

[STRAPI Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RMQK.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DEV This feature seems to be developed yet in Strapi as per [this post](https://forum.strapi.io/t/re-organize-documents-inside-a-collection/541) in their forums. [Here](https://feedback.strapi.io/customization/p/ordering-content-type-entries-in-the-list-view)'s the ongoing feature request